# Using a GridSplitter as a swiper in a listbox

Tags: wpf, layout, gridsplitter

I have a `ListBox` with its contents stretched to fill my Window, and in it I have a grid with two columns (three, including the `GridSplitter`).

I just want to be able to use the `GridSplitter` like a swiper, able to hide/show any amount of either column. ie 100% left side, 50% of each, or 100% right side, etc.

I can't for the life of me make it do that though. The elements on both sides have their own size that they desire to be, and the naive `*` approach doesn't allow the `GridSplitter` to shrink below that size. If I use fixed column sizings I *can* shrink below their desired sizes, but the `GridSplitter` can then run past the end width of the `Window` when resizing the `Window` and the content no longer stretches to fill.

Here's a XamlPad document that best illustrates my problem:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Height="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Red" MinWidth="200" /> <!-- simulate fixed size content /-->
        <Border Background="Purple" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray"
                      ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Lime" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <x:Null />
</ListBox>
```

Most oddly this problem doesn't occur if I don't have the ListBox. It then works exactly how I desire.

Anyway, thank you anyone for any assistance, it'd all be greatly appreciated - this has been driving me nuts :)